# Munin zoom isn't working

Tags: zooming, freebsd, munin

Munin installed on FreeBSD 8.0.
Address: http://site.com/munin/
Path: /usr/local/www/munin/

Problem: zoom is not working (image is not showing). In apache logs I see:

```
[Sun Jan 13 16:42:25 2013] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] File does not exist: /usr/home/site/htdocs, referer: http://site.com/munin/static/dynazoom.html?plugin_name=com%2Fsite.com%2Fhttp_response_time_site&start_iso8601=2013-01-12T08%3A26%3A43%2B0400&stop_iso8601=2013-01-12T14%3A17%3A43%2B0400&start_epoch=1357943743&stop_epoch=1357996393&lower_limit=&upper_limit=&size_x=800&size_y=400&cgiurl_graph=
```

My httpd.conf:

```
Alias /munin/ "/usr/local/www/munin/"
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This looks like an apache configuration issue. It is probably best to ask this on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is over a year old but I'm sure there are other people having this issue and finding this on google. (like me)

This is for *Debian 7.6 +  Munin version 2.0.6-4+deb7u2.* Zoom is actually working but it's localhost only. I didn't test this on Freebsd or any other bsd/linux distros so far but I think the problem&solution will be similar.

Please edit this file:

**/etc/munin/apache2.conf**

```
# Enables fastcgi for munin-cgi-graph if present
ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph
<Location /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph>
        Order allow,deny
#       Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1
        Allow from all
        # AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd
        # AuthName "Munin"
        # AuthType Basic
        # require valid-user
        <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                SetHandler fastcgi-script
        </IfModule>
</Location>

ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-html
<Location /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html>
        Order allow,deny
#       Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1
        Allow from all
        # AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd
        # AuthName "Munin"
        # AuthType Basic
        # require valid-user
        <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                SetHandler fastcgi-script
        </IfModule>
</Location>
```

You will see "Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1" for both munin-cgi-graph and munin-cgi-html. Please comment these lines out and add "Allow from all" (change this depending on your security settings of course) and restart apache2. Now you should be able to zoom to your graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04, and fixed it with these steps:

- Turn off SELINUX: `$ sudo setenforce 0`
- Add this to Apache vhost config: `ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"`
- Change permissions on `/var/log/munin` so that Apache can open files there.

To find out where munin-cgi-graph is installed on your system:

- `find / -name munin-cgi-graph`